# Pandas : Prevent groupby-apply to sort the results according to index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-apply

Say I have a dataframe,

```
dict_ = {
    'Query' : ['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'bat', 'cat', 'rat', 'lion', 'potato', 'london', 'new jersey'],
    'Category': ['fruits', 'fruits', 'fruits', 'animal', 'animal', 'animal', 'animal', 'veggie', 'place', 'place'],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
```

After replicating the groups based on some logic, I see the resultant dataframe has been sorted by the index value.

```
rep_val= df.groupby('Category').size().max()
df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda d: pd.concat(([d]*math.ceil(rep_val/d.shape[0]))).head(rep_val)).reset_index(drop=True)


         Query Category
0          bat   animal
1          cat   animal
2          rat   animal
3         lion   animal
4        apple   fruits
5       banana   fruits
6        mango   fruits
7        apple   fruits
8       london    place
9   new jersey    place
10      london    place
11  new jersey    place
12      potato   veggie
13      potato   veggie
14      potato   veggie
15      potato   veggie
```

However expected was the group appearing first should appear first in the dataframe as well,  so my categories would be `fruits, animal, veggie, place` and their corresponding values

**Expected output :**

```
         Query Category
0        apple   fruits
1       banana   fruits
2        mango   fruits
3        apple   fruits
4          bat   animal
5          cat   animal
6          rat   animal
7         lion   animal
8       potato   veggie
9       potato   veggie
10      potato   veggie
11      potato   veggie
12      london    place
13  new jersey    place
14      london    place
15  new jersey    place
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `sort=False` for the `groupby` method

**CODE**

```
rep_val = df.groupby('Category', sort=False).size().max()
df = df.groupby('Category', sort=False).apply(lambda d: pd.concat(([d] * math.ceil(rep_val / d.shape[0]))).head(rep_val)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
         Query Category
0        apple   fruits
1       banana   fruits
2        mango   fruits
3        apple   fruits
4          bat   animal
5          cat   animal
6          rat   animal
7         lion   animal
8       potato   veggie
9       potato   veggie
10      potato   veggie
11      potato   veggie
12      london    place
13  new jersey    place
14      london    place
15  new jersey    place
```